# Writing to Samba share as different user?

Tags: backup, permissions, samba

I have a Samba share on my NAS drive mounter as follows:

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=backup,password=backups_password //sharebox/SVNBackup /mnt/SVNBackup
```

I am then trying to run:

```
sudo svnadmin dump /usr/local/svn/repos/testrepo > /mnt/SVNBackup/test1.svn
```

but I get:

bash: /mnt/SVNBackup/test1.svn: Permission Denied

The backup location is setup to accept access only from the user "backup" (who doesn't exist on the local system)

How do I go about solving this problem? Thanks

Comment: I found that if I do sudo /bin/bash and then run the command (without sudo) it works. Does this help with a solution? I need to script it eventually so that's why this isn't an acceptable solution that I have found.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo command > outputfile` doesn't do what you think.  Specifically, the outputfile is opened with **your** permissions, not the sudo user's (in this case, root).  That's why it works when you become root and run the command - because then the redirect does run as root, who can write to /mnt/SVNBackup .  It is necessary and sensible that sudo behaves this way.

Find some way of running the whole command as root; put it in root's cron, or write a one-line shell script and invoke **that** with sudo, or find another fix that works for you.  In the limiting (and slightly stupid) case,

```
sudo svnadmin dump /usr/local/svn/repos/testrepo | sudo tee /mnt/SVNBackup/test1.svn
```

should produce the output **both** on stdout **and** in the file `/mnt/SVNBackup/test1.svn` .  Bizarre though it may seem, if you really don't want the output, the simplest way may be to do

```
sudo svnadmin dump /usr/local/svn/repos/testrepo | sudo tee /mnt/SVNBackup/test1.svn > /dev/null
```

If the original svnadmin command produces stuff on STDERR and you want that  in the log file too, try

```
sudo svnadmin dump /usr/local/svn/repos/testrepo 2>&1 | sudo tee /mnt/SVNBackup/test1.svn > /dev/null
```

Note that `2>&1` is a bash forumlation, if your shell is a csh-variant, or something different yet, you'll need to find something appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like the answer I needed, and I suspected that the root after the pipe was the problem but couldn't see an immediate fix since there simply was no "command" there to run as root but simply a path. as for "tee" is there an alternative that I can use and not have it throw the output at stdout? this is a lot of "junk" that I could do without in the log (not that I know exactly what format all this "junk" is going to take.) Essentially, my goal is to have the script run nightly by whichever user is necessary. Does Ubuntu server give me access to roots cron?

Comment: I've amended the answer above accordingly.

Comment: As for access to root's crontab, that's not an Ubuntu question; unless arrangements have been made, normal users have access only to their own crontabs under Unix.  Depending on how your system is set up, you may have access to root privilege via the /bin/su command and the root password, or via the sudo command.  Ask your sysadmin for more details.